# Imagemagick create thumbnail

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I have an image that is 200x200 I want to trim the white space, and make it into an icon that is 32x32.

```
 convert img.png -trim -resize 32x32 imgi.png
```

This line of code does not work, it will not make the canvas a uniform 32x32.  I have tried taking it and adding -canvas 32x32 or -extend 32x32 but then the script does not work at all.

I am doing this from PHP with exec so I do not get an error back.

Answer (score 1):

You can [pad](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#pad) to tweak dimensions of the image after cropping. As of ImageMagick version 6.3.2 you can use `-extent` option to modify end result.

```
convert img.png -trim -resize 32x32 -gravity center -extent 32x32 imgi.png
```

For earlier versions it is necessary to play with `-border`, `-crop` and `+repage`.

```
convert img.png -trim -resize 32x32 -bordercolor white -border 16 -gravity center -crop 32x32+0+0 +repage img.png;
```

Comment: I tested both of these and in both cases the image canvas is coming out 9x32.  Same was without repage.  I read though the examples to come up with what I have now.  Trim takes out all of the transparent space, but then the canvas does not reset to 32x32 with the resize.

Comment: Sorry, I had a problem in my own test so I didn't notice what I tried didn't actually work. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I got the right answer off their forum earlier yesterday, by just asking there.  I appreciate you trying though.